# How to stop usb_gadget returning 'Operation not permitted'

Tags: debian, usb

I have a board running Debian Stretch that acts as a USB gadget, set up in `/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget`.

I am running a script to set up the gadget with new parameters, but statements like this fail:

```
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB
```

I then tried to remove the gadget entirely to run my script fresh:

```
rm -rf /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/
# Result:
rm: cannot remove '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/os_desc/qw_sign': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/os_desc/b_vendor_code': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/os_desc/use': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove '/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/strings/0x409/serialnumber': Operation not permitted
... etc.
```

How can I stop the usb_gadget from running so I can make the changes I need?

Answer (score 2):

*configfs* is a special filesystem that does not allow removing those files.
You can't remove all files recursively.
You have to execute *rmdir* on directories within your *customgadget* instead:

```
rmdir /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/strings/0x409/
rmdir /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/os_desc/
rmdir /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/customgadget/
```

More details: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt